# monit - set verbose mode in monitrc file

Tags: linux, monitor, monit, verbose

in the [monit wiki](https://linux.die.net/man/1/monit) it shows you can run monit in verbose mode using `-vv` when running from the command line.

If I run `ps -ef` to see the monit command, I see:

```
root        42     1  0 19:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/monit -vv -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

which is what I want.

now say I do `service monit restart` - than run `ps -ef` again, it starts without the `-vv` flag.

```
root        42     1  0 19:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

in the docs its also stated:

> The following options are recognized by monit. However, it is recommended that you set options (when applicable) directly in the .monitrc control file.

I couldn't find any docs on how to set verbose mode in the monitrc file, is there any way to do this?

Comment: `say I do service monit restart`Check `/etc/rc.d/.../monit` and see if it uses `/etc/sysconfig/monit` and modify one or the other and add `-vv` option to service.

Comment: Thanks, was able to find “/etc/default/monit” and added the extra args there.